# How can I add empty space at the bottom and right of an icCube report?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Is there a way to add empty space at the bottom and right of a report? I could add an empty text box in the bottom right corner, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report's dimensions are auto-calculated only in case there are no **CSS** rules that define width and height of a report's container/layout.

Due to that, if you have exact dimensions of a report - you may want to use **Report CSS** configuration under **Configuration** menu.

With something like this as a value:

```
.ic3-fixed-layout {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
}
```

This solution is handy due to the fact that it's bound to a specific report and each report may have it's own size.